# Letsencrypt/certbot on Debian Stretch: ImportError: cannot import name jose

Tags: python, lets-encrypt

After installing and using the certbot script offered by the Debian package (version 0.10.2), I got the request to supply a wildcard certificate. As that is not possible with the certbot version from the Debian repo, I went to upgrade the certbot.

The most pythony way seemed to upgrade using pip:

```
pip install certbot --upgrade
```

After upgrading, certbot stopped working because of version conflicts. My guess is that this line

```
load_entry_point('certbot==0.10.2', 'console_scripts', 'certbot')()
```

prevents the

```
/usr/bin/certbot
```

script frontend to run with a newer python package version of certbot. Now, I'm almost back to having the original Debian version running, but this problem persists:

```
  File "/usr/bin/certbot", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('certbot==0.10.2', 'console_scripts', 'certbot')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 484, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2707, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2325, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2331, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/certbot/main.py", line 13, in <module>
    from acme import jose
```

As far as I can see (so far I'm no Python expert), the `acme` package is installed:

```
root@cloud:~# pip show acme
Name: acme
Version: 0.26.1
Summary: ACME protocol implementation in Python
Home-page: https://github.com/letsencrypt/letsencrypt
Author: Certbot Project
Author-email: client-dev@letsencrypt.org
License: Apache License 2.0
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requires: cryptography, six, pytz, PyOpenSSL, pyrfc3339, setuptools, requests, josepy, requests-toolbelt, mock
```

I can get the same error message by creating a small test script and running it with just

```
from acme import jose
```

as contents:

```
root@cloud:~# python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from acme import jose
ImportError: cannot import name jose
```

I would appreciate a helping hand before delving into the depths of Python package management.

Comment: You've somehow mixed up system Python packages with manually installed Python packages. Good luck.

Comment: If I knew how, I would like to reinstall the python packages with the version number supplied by Stretch. I've tried finding out which package of Debian supplies the Python package `acme`, unsuccessfully so far. The Debian package search shows multiple packages with `acme` in their name and with Python relevance (python-acme-doc python-acme acmetool acme-tiny), yet reinstalling them doesn't seem to have any effect.